# Триггер на добавление в List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, хочу что бы перед добавление записи в коллекцию у меня выполнялось некоторое действие.

Как я понимаю, мне нужно наследоваться от `List<T>` и перекрывать метод `Add` своим или есть еще какие-то варианты?
В конечном итоге, для пользователя должно казаться, что он работает с обычным List'ом.

Comment: [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @tym32167, как я понимаю, событие срабатывает после добавления, а мне нужно перед.

Comment: Уверены, что надо пилить свою структуру данных? Нет возможности просто вызывать что то до добавления элемента в список в своем коде?

Comment: Не выйдет так просто, `List<T>.Add` невиртуальный.

Comment: @VladD, да, но его же можно перекрыть, добавив new к методу. Чем это плохо?

Comment: Вам придётся пилить собственную реализацию `IList<T>` (можно спроксировать к внутреннему экземпляру `List<T>`), и уболтать клиентский код не требовать точный тип.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Тем, что если у клиента тип `List<T>`, то он вызовет внутренний, неперекрытый метод `Add`. Попробуйте сами.

Comment: @VladD, думаю, что класс, который реализует IList<T> и оборачивается List<T>, то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Наследуйтесь от [класса `Collection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx), в нем есть специальные protected virtual методы для этого, в частности `InsertItem`, например. Т.е. вы можете переопределить этот метод в своем наследнике и в нем выполнить необходимые операции, а затем вызвать базовую реализацию, которая фактически вставит элемент (или не вызывать, если в каких-то ситуациях вставка не нужна).

Примером наследования от `Collection` как раз является упомянутый класс `ObservableCollection` ([здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,210) можно посмотреть как это реализовано в нем)

PS: Если вы читали Албахари, то должны так же знать о классе `CollectionBase` - необобщенной версии `Collection<T>`.

Comment: А плох ли вариант, создания собственного класса с реализацией IList<T>, который является оболочкой над List<T>. Т.е внутри реализации интерфейса выполняются необходимые действия перед добавлением данных в List. Или это дело вкуса и такой подход имеет место быть?

Comment: Можно и так, но это более трудозатратно - вам придется заняться бесполезным перенаправлением всех вызовов свойств и методов внутреннему списку. Наследование же позволит вам сэкономить на этом и написать только нужный функционал. Прокси-класс Collection<T> как раз предназначен именно для того, чтобы можно было легко расширить функционал, надо пользоваться тем, что предоставляет фреймворк.

Comment: @iluxa1810, сравните количество кода: https://pastebin.com/byrCDSiY

Comment: @АндрейNOP: «`public int Count => ((IList<T>)list).Count;`» — а зачем cast?

Comment: @VladD, это автоматическая реализация студией, я править не стал :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Если убрать cast, будет выглядеть не так ужасно :)

Comment: @VladD, количество строк кода от этого не убавится. Если причесать, можно и фигурные скобки повыбрасывать, сжать методы до выражений. Но зачем, если есть специальный класс Collection<T>? Зачем переписывать дюжину методов, если нас фактически интересует всего один?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0L4jqJgQ @VladD, лучше? :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Выглядит лучше :) Но да, количество методов там и тут сильно отличается.